# delete rows from dataframe python

Tags: python

`EXPIRY_DT` column of dataframe contains unique dates, i want to delete dates other than

`24-Jun-21`. when i run this code all rows gets deleted.

```
df1.drop(df1[df1['EXPIRY_DT'] != '24-Jun-21'].index, inplace=True)
```

i am unable to understand why this is happening.
because i have used this same method on one other column and it worked fine.

```
df1.drop(df1[df1['INSTRUMENT'] != 'FUTSTK'].index, inplace=True)            // this worked
```

only difference between this two columns that i can see is as follows
[some leading space is there in case of dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXcMp.png)

how to solve this issue?

**update:**

```
{'INSTRUMENT': {0: 'FUTIDX', 1: 'FUTIDX', 2: 'FUTIDX', 3: 'FUTIDX', 4: 'FUTIDX'}, 'SYMBOL': {0: 'BANKNIFTY', 1: 'BANKNIFTY', 2: 'BANKNIFTY', 3: 'FINNIFTY', 4: 'FINNIFTY'}, 'EXPIRY_DT': {0: '24-Jun-2021', 1: '29-Jul-2021', 2: '26-Aug-2021', 3: '03-Jun-2021', 4: '10-Jun-2021'}, 'STRIKE_PR': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}, 'OPTION_TYP': {0: 'XX', 1: 'XX', 2: 'XX', 3: 'XX', 4: 'XX'}, 'OPEN': {0: 35280.0, 1: 
35371.6, 2: 35515.15, 3: 16400.05, 4: 16492.2}, 'HIGH': {0: 35650.0, 1: 35769.7, 2: 35886.55, 3: 16676.5, 4: 16703.85}, 'LOW': {0: 35063.15, 1: 35205.1, 2: 35325.0, 3: 16400.05, 4: 16469.45}, 'CLOSE': {0: 35602.9, 1: 35724.95, 2: 35848.3, 3: 16657.35, 4: 16663.3}, 'SETTLE_PR': 
{0: 35602.9, 1: 35724.95, 2: 35848.3, 3: 16657.35, 4: 16663.3}, 'CONTRACTS': {0: 141916, 1: 2603, 2: 540, 3: 84, 4: 8}, 'VAL_INLAKH': {0: 1257088.18, 1: 23143.88, 2: 4819.29, 3: 555.97, 4: 53.09}, 'OPEN_INT': {0: 1723450, 1: 61975, 2: 5700, 3: 1640, 4: 240}, 'CHG_IN_OI': {0: -21550, 1: 1000, 2: 500, 3: 360, 4: -40}, 'TIMESTAMP': {0: '31-MAY-2021', 1: '31-MAY-2021', 2: '31-MAY-2021', 3: '31-MAY-2021', 4: '31-MAY-2021'}, 'Unnamed: 15': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}}
```

Comment: For debugging you could print `df1[df1['EXPIRY_DT'] != '24-Jun-21']` to see what is actually in the selection. My guess is that the date is of type `datetime` and not `str`. Could print `df.dtypes`?

Comment: @Rafael-WO data type is object

Comment: printing df1[df1['EXPIRY_DT'] != '24-Jun-21'] prints all the data including 24 -jun-21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is leading space, you can first `strip` off the spaces and then perform the action

```py
df1.drop(df1[df1['EXPIRY_DT'].str.strip() != '24-Jun-21'].index, inplace=True)
```

**PS**: `'24-Jun-21'` is not same as `' 24-Jun-21'`

**EDIT**:
If the method mentioned above doesn't work, do this: `df1[:5].to_dict()` and add the output data to the question, Can't assist further until you add the exact data as plain text

**UPDATE**:

The data you have added doesn't have the value like `'24-Jun-21'` the value is like `24-Jun-2021` which is obviously different.

Change the value to `24-Jun-2021` and it will work:

```py
df1.drop(df1[df1['EXPIRY_DT'].str.strip() != '24-Jun-2021'].index, inplace=True)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
df1
  INSTRUMENT     SYMBOL    EXPIRY_DT  ...  CHG_IN_OI    TIMESTAMP  Unnamed: 15
0     FUTIDX  BANKNIFTY  24-Jun-2021  ...     -21550  31-MAY-2021          NaN
```

Comment: this didnt work,  i thought there is leading space, because i can see it visually, i dont know exactly

Comment: Do this: `df1[:5].to_dict()` and add the output data to the question, Can't assist further until you add the exact data as plain text, and also add what you mean by it didn't work, did it threw any error?

Comment: i have added the output data to question

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the year as 21 instead of 2021

```
df1.drop(df1[df1['EXPIRY_DT'] != '24-Jun-2021'].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I agree. It's an issue of `str` comparison.

Comment: yes this was the issue, but as you can see the image year was 21